# Is it possible to customize material's datepicker body?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

The idea is to edit the datepicker body in order to add a button. I know it is possible to edit the header, but I'd like to add a button (that upon being pressed sets the calendar date to today's date) below the actual dates.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to edit the body of the calendar. However, I ended up adding the button from the CalendarHeaderComponent. It is not an ideal situation but it gets the job done and since I already had the header customized, it wasn't much extra effort.

The html (add the following to your custom calendar header):

```
<button (click)="goToToday()" class="today-button" mat-button color="link">Today</button>
```

The css:

```
.today-button {
  position: relative;
  top: 280px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

Extra css in the actual datepicker itself:

```
.mat-datepicker-content {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```